# アプリケーションレベルでのデータの一貫性チェックについて

Tags: sql

データベースでトランザクションを実行してテーブルにselectを行い、データが存在しないことを確認した上でinsert処理を行う場合に並列でほぼ同時にトランザクションが走ると、お互いにコミットされていないためselectでの存在チェックをすり抜け、insert処理が複数実行されてしまうケースを改善するためにはトランザクションレベルを上げるか、またはテーブルに対してデータが重複しないようにユニークキーを設定するしかないのでしょうか？アプリケーションレベルでの回避は困難なのでしょうか？

追記
RDBMSを使用し(出来ればMysqlかPostgres)、PKをAUTO_INCREMENTに設定している場合です。
ユニークキーを設定した場合や、テーブルロックを行った場合は重複が防げると理解しているのですが、それ以外の方法で回避する方法はないのか知りたいです。
updateの場合はselect for updateを使用すれば該当の行のみをロックすることができますが、insertの場合は対象の行が存在しないため行レベルでのロックが行えないため、ロックするにしてもテーブルロックしか方法がないのかと思っています。

アプリケーションレベルでのトランザクション内で更新とチェックはよくあることだと思うのですが、それに対して他のアプローチや回避策がないかと思い質問させて頂きました。決してRDBMSの機能を一切使わないわけではありません。

Comment: トランザクションレベルはアイソレーションレベルの間違いですね。それはともかく`SELECT FOR UPDATE`文でロックするのが良いでしょう。ロックを使いたくない何らかの理由があれば、行にバージョンカラムを設けて、更新されるたびにカウントアップします。UPDATE時にPK+当該のカウントの行が存在しなければ誰かが先にUPDATEしたと判断できます。オプティミスティックロックで検索してみてください。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。select for updateは対象のレコードが存在しない場合はロックできないと思っているのですが、間違いでしょうか？その場合はオプティミスティックロックしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 重複しているレコードがすでに存在していることを挿入前にアプリケーションが検出出来なければならないのか、結果として重複したレコードが出来なければよいのか、どちらでしょうか。また、RDBMSにこだわらない方法が必要なのか、特定のRDBMSを前提としているのかどちらでしょうか。回答はコメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: なんでアプリケーションで実装したいのですか? DBで実装されている機能を自分で実装しても、バグってないかなぁ?と心配事が増えるだけな気がしたので。

Comment: レコードが存在しない時に排他制御したい例は滅多にないので読み飛ばしてしまいました。普通はPKエラーになってINSERTできませんから。INSERTが重複してしまうということはPKが正しくセットされていないか、PKをAUTO_INCREMENTとかtimestampにしているからでは？その場合何をもってして重複だと判断していますか？その条件に従ってUNIQUE制約を設定すれば良いと思います。もうちょっと具体的な例を書いてもらえると助かります。

Comment: 一意制約を使えるが使いたくないと言う話だと思って回答しましたが、質問を読み直してみたら勘違いでしたので削除しました

Comment: 「他のトランザクションでINSERTしたデータが見えない」かつ「分離レベルがSERIALIZABLEではない」とは、どのトランザクション分離レベルを指したうえでの質問でしょうか。MySQLのREPEATABLE READはファントムリードしないようですが、それ以外にある？

Comment: 質問の要件を満していないので、解答を削除しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問文で除外されいてるパターンも含めて整理し直します。

- データベースによる解決

  - 「selectでの存在チェック」と同じ内容でユニークキーを設定することで`INSERT`時に自動的に存在チェックを行うことができます。「selectでの存在チェック」が不要になるため効率がいいです。
  - 「selectでの存在チェック」が複雑でユニークキーを設定できない場合、`TRIGGER`を設定することで、`INSERT`時に自動的に存在チェックを行うことができます。アプリケーション側からの明示的な「selectでの存在チェック」が不要になるため効率がいいです。
  - [`MERGE`文](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MERGE_(SQL))を使用することで存在しない場合にのみ`INSERT`を行うことができます。同時に存在する場合に`UPDATE`や`DELETE`を行うこともできます。
    ただし事前にテンポラリテーブルなどに格納する必要があったり、対応しているデータベースエンジンが限られます。もっとも「selectでの存在チェック」の内容を`ON`句に記述するため、そうであればそもそもユニークキーが設定できそうです。
  - トランザクション分離レベルを上げることでファントム読み取りを防止します。「selectでの存在チェック」を行うとデータベースによって「`INSERT`予定の行が存在しないこと」も保証され、複数実行は防止されます。
    （ただし範囲ロックが使われるため偽の失敗が発生します…だっけ？）
  - テーブルロックを行うことで、根本的に複数実行を防止します。
- アプリケーションによる解決

  - アプリケーションレベルで排他処理を行うことで、根本的に複数実行を防止します。

Comment: トランザクションを用いることでアプリケーション側で一貫性のチェックを行うのは極一般的な用法ですが、何か勘違いされていませんか。「アプリケーションで排他制御を行えばアプリケーションレベルで一貫性はチェック出来る」は確かに事実ですが、トランザクションというかデータベースそのものの存在意義を否定してしまっています。

Comment: @suzukis 「データベースレベルで一貫性チェックを行わない」というデータベースの存在意義のかなり否定した条件下での回答であり、一般論を答えたものではありません。また「データベースレベルでトランザクションを使用するのであればデータベースレベルで一貫性をチェックすべきです。」とも答えているのにデータベースの存在意義を否定する回答だと言うのですか？

Comment: メタな話で申し訳ないですが、そもそも質問者が何でこれをしたいのか? が分からないと答えにくくないですか? @suzukis さんが書いているみたいに UI の事を気にしているのかもしれないし、単なる興味本意なのかもしれないし、その他思いもよらない事なのかもしれない。多分そこを各解答者が自分の想像力で思い思いに埋めて答えてるんだと思いますが、周りが色々書いてるだけで肝心の質問者が何も反応しないし。個人的には、こういう考え方もあるんだなという事が分かっていいかなと思いますし、説明考えるのも好きでやっているので問題ないです。それと後から第3者が見ても役に経つ可能性はあるのかなと思います。ただこのサイトの主旨に合っているかは分かりません。

Comment: あとそもそも、僕の能力が低い所為もあると思いますが、少なくとも何でこれをしたいのか? という点においては質問が分かりにくいです。でも分かりにくいのは仕方ないと思います。誰だって思い込みとかあって、自分の文章を他人が読んでどう思うかまで想像できないですから。だから、質問者はもっと解答に反応して欲しいと思います。でもそうならないのは、そうしようと思わせない空気がココにあるからかもしれません。なんかこういう人達とやりとりしたくないなと思われちゃったとか。そういう場合は、ネット上で一見さんの空気を読むのは不可能に近いと思うので、仕方ないのかもしれません。もしくは、質問者が実名でも固定ハンドルネームでもないので放置しているだけないかもしれないです。

Comment: 繰り返しますが、データベースではなくアプリケーションレベルで一貫性のチェックを行うことは一般的によくあります。この場合、普通は更新とチェックを一つのトランザクションとして処理します。これが一般的な状況でないと言われるのなら見解の相違としか言いようがないですね。トランザクションをどのように定義するかはアプリケーションレベルの話で、それがどのような意図なのかはDB側は知ったことではありません。にもかかわらず意図によって良い悪いがあるのだ、制約をアプリケーションで実装するのに使ってはならないというのは不合理でしょう。

Comment: コメント欄でディスカッションを行わないでください。